# How domain coloring is done for a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

Please explain me the concept and the technique behind the "Domain coloring" of a complex function possibly with some example. please describe it as easily as you can..because I am new in complex analysis and keenly interested to learn to graph them to know their characteristics.things get very difficult to me when it goes to four dimensions.So,please describe softly.Thank you....

Comment: This is explained in many places, just google it... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring, http://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex/domain_coloring.html, etc.

Comment: I did so...but have some confusions in many places.so,that's why I need a step by step guideline with a proper example.could you please help me with that?

Comment: Well, I myself wrote the second of the pages that I linked to (which I think goes step by step and has lots of examples), so if you don't understand that, why would you understand what I'd write here? Your question is very broad, and I think you'll have a much better chance of getting a good answer if you ask specifically about the steps you don't understand in this or that explanation.

Comment: Sorry, not really interested in that...

Comment: It's ok....thank you